# What structure to use to read data from CSV file?

Tags: java, csv, multidimensional-array

I'm still having issues **creating an array to store the infos of my CSV file**.
Here is an example of my csv - file.

```
Time;Data0;Data1;Data2;
27.08.2013 00:00:00;nan;nan;nan;
27.08.2013 00:10:00;0;1;2;
```

As you can see, they are 3 types.
-String : name of the column (e.g `Time`), or  `nan` -NotANumber-.
-Double  : for the values of `Data0`, `Data1`, `Data2`.
-Timestamp  : for the `Time` value.

The name of the columns are always on the first line of the file.
I can have a very huge number of rows and columns.

So now **my question:** what is the easiest way of getting those information, and storing them in an Array - like form ?
I need to access the informations easily, by example by searching the field named `Data0` i want to be able to access to `nan` and to `0`.

**What i did :** I tried to store this into a map, but it was not what I wanted (or obviously I didn't used it right). Furthermore I was limited to two elements, I have three.
I also tried to do this in an array, but because an array can be defined only after one type in Java, I tried to make it after a class:

```
public class StorageArray {
    String nameColumn;
    Double contentLine;
    Timestamp time;
}
```

But then I couldn't figure out how to store the different types in the different variables in my class.

I'm a Java beginner, so maybe there is an easy way to do what I want?
If you want me to provide more code, I can, but I wanted to keep the question as simple as possible.

A friend told me to use **introspection** and **object-relational mapping** (ORM). But it seems quite difficult for me.

Comment: Basic implementation: use a plain `List<List<String>> csvData`. You can find an example from mkyong that uses `String[]` to read every line: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/

Comment: You can try Map<String,StorageArray> cvMap = new HashMap<String,StorageArray>(); basicall decide on the key and have StorageArray Bean as the value in the map.

Comment: @Ankit But what should StorageArray be? same as my class?
But how can i put the elements in in the correct type?
And how to avoid to have multiple times the same key for my values?
What is exactly an StorageArray Bean? :/
(sorry for the multiple questions)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yup, i did find this example to, but my problem is not on the parsing, it's more on the storage.
Because he is using only a simple String array, which is not i want :/

Comment: Its just a java bean, if the format is always Time;Data0;Data1;Data2; and you do need Data0 Data1 Data2 etc as individual columns then its beter to have HashMap<key, StorageArray> with StorageArray having the String data0; String Data1; String Data2 etc. Else if it is just a String you can have HashMap<key, String> and then can run String.split(";") on this string to break this string

Comment: First, read the data as `String`, then parse it to whatever you want/need. If the data is a `Date`, then use a `SimpleDateFormat` to convert the `String` into `Date`, if is an `int` then use `Integer.parseInt(String)`, if you don't know the exact format, keep it as `String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need `Double contentLine`.

Use `LinkedHashMap<String /*nameColumn*/,Timestamp /*time*/ >`.

Stored index in your map its your row.

Other way, use `Linkedlist<SomeYourClass>` where `SomeYourClass` is represented your row (I think it will be easy to handle):

```
public class Row
{
List<String> nameColumnList;
//Double contentLine; /* you don't need it*/
Timestamp time;
// ...
}
```